# How to do this very specific concatenation and transform an array to list using Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

First off, sorry for any grammatical errors, I'm not a native English speaker.

My problem is as follows: I have a very big dataset which contains populational data of a given city (row) in a given year (collum). I want to transform this table as to have the city and year concatenated (Ex: Los Angeles 2001, and under it, Los Angeles 2002, etc.) and the populational data to the right side, also in a single collum (two in total).

I made a mockup of what I need, given my limited English skills, I can only explain it so far. [image]

- I have tried using the concatenate function, but I did not get very far. My version of Excel doesn't have the TOCOL function.
- Doing it by hand is out of question, it is just too big.
- If you don't know a perfect solution, some pointers would come a long way. I would be thankful just to know if excel is the appropriate tool here.

Comment: which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2016

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=HSTACK(TOCOL(A2:A6&B1:E1),TOCOL(B2:E6))
```

Comment: My Excel version doesn't include TOCOL and HSTACK functions i believe.

Answer (score 1):

For older versions of Excel you can use formulas as on the screenshot.
[image: conversion 2D to columns]

Or without this `G2:J6` area you can enter in `L2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6 & $B$1:$E$1,(ROW(A1)-1)/4+1,MOD(ROW(A1)-1,COLUMNS($B$2:$E$6))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete answer to your question. I have a solution to convert the array of values into a list.
Use the following formula `=TRANSPOSE(HSTACK(C3:F3,C4:F4,C5:F5,C6:F6,C7:F7))`

[image: screenshot showing the transpose-hstack formula]

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query to get the result:

1. Select the Range- go to Data- From Table/Range- My Table have Headers:
   [image]

2.Open Power Query editor- select Column 1 to 4- Transform tab- Unpivot Columns:
[image]

3. Select Column Column1 and Attribute- Right click- select Merge Columns- Click OK:
   [image]
4. Go to Home tab- Close & Load:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you've explicitly stated your version of excel does not have functions like HSTACK or TOCOL, and you've also tagged `VBA`, open the Visual Basic editor (Alt+F11) and paste the following code into a new module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UnpivotData()

'Load the current data range into an array
    Dim currentData As Variant
    currentData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

'Set the dimensions of the output data
    Dim lRows As Long, data() As Variant
    lRows = (UBound(currentData, 1) - 1) * (UBound(currentData, 2) - 1)
    ReDim data(1 To lRows, 1 To 2)

'Transform the data, row by row, column by column
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rowId As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(currentData, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(currentData, 2)
            rowId = rowId + 1
            data(rowId, 1) = currentData(i, 1) & currentData(1, j)
            data(rowId, 2) = currentData(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

'Write the transformed data to the output range
    With ActiveSheet.Range("H1")
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
    End With

End Sub
```

The above code will output the desired results, regardless of the number of rows or columns in your data range. Simply adjust the two range references to meet your needs.

**Figure 1:** Results after running the code...
[image: unpivot_data.png]